# Flutter how to reorder firebase documents in a streambuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to reorder firebase documents in a stream builder. Now I am sorting the documents by date. But I want it possible to change it to my custom order.

I am using this code:

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection(widget.user!.uid)
                            .orderBy("date", descending: false)
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                          
                          return Theme(
                              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                                canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
                                shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                              ),
                              child: ReorderableListView(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                                  print(oldIndex);
                                  print(newIndex);
                                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection(widget.user!.uid)
                                      .doc('document')
                                      .update({"position": newIndex});
                                },
                                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 30),
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                children: getExpenseItems(snapshot),
                              ));
                        }))
```

But I dont know how to continue. Does anyone know what I can do to solve this?

Comment: you have to save date or timestamp in document